# A space $W$ consists of polynomials of degree $k$ for all $0≤k≤n$. Is $W$ equal to the whole space of polynomials of degree $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ which is the space of all polynomials up to degree $n$. $W$ consists of polynomials of degree $k$ for all $0≤k≤n$ (to clarify, at least $1$ polynomial of each degree $k$ is in $W$). Is it true that $W=V$?

I think it's true. I tried proving this by showing containment and equality of dimensions. Obviously $W$ is contained in $V$. But I'm not sure how to show that their dimensions are equal. How do I take $n$ polynomials of different degrees from $W$ and show they are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_k \in W$ be a polynomial of degree $k$, for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, n$. The indexed family $(f_0, \ldots, f_n)$ is linearly independent. To see this, you can write each $f_k$ in the basis $(1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^n)$ of $V$. If $a_{k, j}$  ($0 \leq j \leq k$) are the coefficients of $f_k$, then the matrix of the family $(f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ in this basis has the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} &  \cdots & \cdots & a_{1,n}\\
0 & a_{2,2} &   &   & a_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &   & \vdots\\
\vdots &   & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & a_{n,n}\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
and is thus invertible. Therefore, $W$ contains an indexed family composed of $n$ linearly independant vectors, hence it has dimension $\geq n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint/answer: Write $W=\{p_0,\cdots,p_n\}$ where $p_k$ is a polynomial in $W$ of degree $k$ and suppose that $W$ wasn't linearly independent. Then that would mean that $a_0p_0+\cdots a_np_n=0$ and not all $a_n=0$ being $0$ could both be true. But if not all $a_n=0$, look at the highest (in terms of degree) nonzero term. What does that tell you about the degree of $a_0p_0+\cdots+a_np_n$?